# Django LoginRequired mixin always deny access

Tags: jquery, python, django

**My don't work view:** A class  based view

```py
class DatabasesViewAll(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    raise_exception = True

    def get(self, request):
        print( request.session.get('user_id'))
        databases = Database.objects.all()
        serialized_databases = serializers.serialize('json', databases)
        return JsonResponse({'result':'success', 'data':serialized_databases})

    def post(self, request):
        return JsonResponse({'result':'error', 'message':'Operação Inválida'})
```

**My login view:** ( simple method view )

```
def std_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        # Authentication Successfull
        if user is not None:
            request.session['user_id'] = user.id
            database = Database.objects.get(dweller__profile__user=user)

        # Authentication failed
        else:
            response_data = {}
            response_data['result'] = 'error'
            response_data['message'] = 'Usuário ou senha inválido.'
            return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

When accessing this view from a Jquery ( or anywhere) get/post ajax it always gets me an error;

> FORBIDDEN(Permission Denied)

Even when I did logon before.

When I remove the LoginRequiredMixin from the view class, I can print the user_id on the console, with is None, in fact, when I'm not logged, or the id of the user that logged. So I can assume my login methods are working ( the default django auth ).

What the criteria for the  LoginRequired mixin accepts my request? I thought that just the existance of a 'request.session.get('user_id')' different from None would be enough, but apparently there are some more criterias to bem satisfacted.. how is the right way to use this mixin?

**EDIT:**

My login view ( the only one which should be 'public' ):

```
@csrf_exempt
def std_login(request):
```

If I remove the csrf_exempt decorator, I got access denied even in the std_login method, which does not about LoginRequired mixin or decorator

Only for a matter of tests, I removed the CSRF Middleware from my settings, and now I can use my std_login method back again, and I'm able to successuful log me in, but the LoginRequiredMixin stills deny my acess. Note that I'm trying to access a GET method, not a POST.

I'm trying to consume the services of my Django Backend app through a second app, so there is some CORS here. I'm using an popular django app named 'django-cors-headers' which works fine when I call my **std_login** method that dont uses the LoginRequiredMixin, and if I remove the LoginRequiredMixin on my view class everything works nice, so I can assume that the CORS is not the problem here, and as said, I temporaly removed the CRSF Middleware as well.

Maybe the Mixin can't work in a CORS scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LoginRequiredMixin simply checks that a user is authenticated:

```
class LoginRequiredMixin(AccessMixin):  
      if not request.user.is_authenticated():
           return self.handle_no_permission()
      return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In your login view you must have:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login
user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
login(request,user)
```

Note that if you add a  `{% csrf_token %}` tag to the login form you will not need the csrf_exempt, django will auto populate this tag, and it's safer.

Comment: I edited my question with some pertinent concerns, but at the end the problem was my misunderstooding in what is **authenticate** and what is **login** . I was checking if the user credentials were right, but not calling the login() method uppon sucessfully auth. Thnaks.